# Unable to extract time alone despite date and datetime being successful

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, formatting, dplyr

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
startdate <-c('10/29/2318 11:43','10/29/2311 11:43','11/19/2108 11:43')

employ <- data.frame(startdate)
```

I am trying to extract the `date,datetime and time` components. Despite being successful with `date and datetime`, for some reason the same operation doesn't work well for `time` extraction.

Please find my code below

```
transform_dates = function(DF){
    DF %>% 
       mutate(measurement_date = as.Date(startdate,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>%
       mutate(measurement_datetime = format(as.POSIXct(startdate,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d %T")) %>%
       mutate(measurement_time = format(as.POSIXct(startdate,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M"))  # also tried with `%T`
 }
        # the code throws error in `measurement_time` line

transform_dates(employ)
```

I get the below output successfully for two columns

[image]

Can you help me understand why the same `format` method doesn't work for `measurement_time` column? instead i get this error

> Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
>     character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

But I expect my output to have another column called `measurement_time` column as well which will look like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it once to datetime and then use `as.Date` and `format` to get date and time respectively

```
library(dplyr)

transform_dates = function(DF){
  DF %>% 
    mutate(measurement_datetime = as.POSIXct(startdate, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
           measurement_date = as.Date(measurement_datetime), 
           measurement_time = format(measurement_datetime, "%T"))
}

transform_dates(employ)

#         startdate measurement_datetime measurement_date measurement_time
#1 10/29/2318 11:43  2318-10-29 11:43:00       2318-10-29         11:43:00
#2 10/29/2311 11:43  2311-10-29 11:43:00       2311-10-29         11:43:00
#3 11/19/2108 11:43  2108-11-19 11:43:00       2108-11-19         11:43:00
```

---

The reason OP's attempt didn't work is because they were missing `format` argument in `as.POSIXct` for the last call. The second argument is `tz` in `as.POSIXct` by default unless explicitly mentioned. Also we don't need multiple `mutate` statement here. So integrating the above changes, the following works.

```
employ %>% 
  mutate(measurement_date = as.Date(startdate,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), 
         measurement_datetime = format(as.POSIXct(startdate,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),"%Y-%m-%d %T"),
         measurement_time = format(as.POSIXct(startdate,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M"))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Upvoted. But would you mind also letting me know on what's wrong with my statment for `measurement_time`?

Comment: @SSMK you are missing the `format` argument in `as.POSIXct`. `mutate(measurement_time = format(as.POSIXct(startdate,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),"%H:%M"))  ` would have worked.

Comment: Thank you. Will mark the answer after time limit is over. Using multiple mutates with %>%` is same as one single mutate enclosed in parenthesis? Trying to understand the difference between your and my code

Comment: @SSMK yes, in this case it is the same. So a single `mutate` call is sufficient.

Comment: In addition, just curious to learn and understand. In the first line of mutate, is it any different if I use just plain `startdate` instead `.$startdate`. Both are same. Am I right?

Comment: in this case, yes both will be same. But if you have `group_by` somewhere in the chain then both would not be the same.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a link where I can learn about this? I did a search but couldn't find a link where I can learn the difference between two

Comment: I don't know any resources related to it but when using chains (`>%>`) you don't need to use `$` to extract columns.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to get the measurement would be to remove everything before it on the string

```
employ%>%mutate(measurement_time = sub(".* (.*)","\\1",startdate))
         startdate measurement_time
1 10/29/2318 11:43            11:43
2 10/29/2311 11:43            11:43
3 11/19/2108 11:43            11:43
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. Upvoted. But can you let me know what's the issue with my format statment?

Comment: @Ronak Shah has the answer for you

Answer (score 2):

A `lubridate-dplyr-tidyr`(`tidyverse`) approach:

```
employ %>% 
   mutate(startdate=lubridate::mdy_hm(startdate)) %>% 
   tidyr::separate(startdate, into= c("Date", "Time"), sep = " ")
        Date     Time
1 2318-10-29 11:43:00
2 2311-10-29 11:43:00
3 2108-11-19 11:43:00
```